# Is the pointer returned by `malloc()` a constant pointer in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, implicit-conversion

I know that the name of an array is a constant pointer. I am wondering what is the case for the pointer returned by `malloc()`? Is it a constant pointer?

Comment: The name of an array is a pointer. It's constant because it's a name. malloc() returns a pointer. I don't understand what "constant" could mean for malloc.

Comment: malloc returns the address of the allocation, you can assign it to a constant pointer or not.

Comment: The name of an array is not a pointer, whether constant or not. If `foo` is an array, then `sizeof foo` gives the size of the array, not the size of a pointer, and `&foo` gives an address of type “pointer to array,” not “pointer to pointer.” When an array is used in an expression, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, is the operand of unary `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Comment: What difference could it possibly make if the trivially copyable value type returned from `malloc()` _was_ `const`? You can assign it to a non-const pointer anyway. What do you believe it would mean if it _were_ a "constant pointer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that the name of an array is a constant pointer.

You are mistaken. Arrays are not pointers. But used in expressions with rare exceptions they are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements that a rvalues. Arrays themselves are non-modifiable lvalues.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

The function malloc returns a value of the address of the allocated memory. It is not a constant pointer. But as it is an rvalue you may not assign a new value to the returned pointer.

And as `@John Bollinger` correctly mentioned in a comment the return type of the function `malloc` is `void *` not `void * const`.

Comment: And the well-documented signature of `malloc()` leaves no room for doubt: it returns `void *`, not `void * const`.  Not that the latter would be meaningfully different anyway, as you observe.

Answer (score -1):

What malloc(MEM_SIZE) returns is not a constant, usually a "readable and writable" memory space address.

The size of the readable and writable space is MEM_SIZE. If the MEM_SIZE is exceeded, the program will throw a memory out-of-bounds error. With luck the program will crash, with bad luck you will feel fine.

Comment: The OP is drawing an analogy with array declarations.  It seems then that they are not asking about whether the allocated space is `const` (which would make `malloc` useless), but whether *the pointer to it* is `const`.

Comment: C programs don't "throw a memory out-of-bounds error", and there's no requirement about what a program does when you invoke undefined behaviour (such as referring outside the bounds to the memory allocated to you by `malloc()`).  It may crash; it may produce the wrong answer; it may appear to work as intended — all are possible.  The gist of your answer is correct, but some of the details are dubious.